# Windows 7 laptop resume from hibernate not using built-in screen

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, docking-station

When I'm at work, I have my Dell Precision M4500/Windows 7 machine on a docking station, lid closed, and displaying on dual external monitors.  I put the machine into sleep or hibernate to travel.  But, when I try to bring it back up without the docking station, it acts like it's still trying to display on the external monitors--the laptop screen itself is dark.  The only way I've ever been able to use it after a hibernate without the docking station is by either doing a hard shutdown, or putting it back on the same docking station.

The laptop screen is active while the waking-up process works (i.e. I can see the logos and the words "Resuming Windows") but after that I just get a screen showing black.  Note that the laptop screen is on, rather than disabled--it just shows a completely black screen.

If I shut the machine down on the docking station, then it starts up just fine by itself.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not find anything specific searching the Dell forums, Update to the latest bios and video driver is a good start.

Comment: Only one related post...http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/p/19337908/19717775.aspx#19717775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bios updates for that model, the latest bios update will include all previous fixes.

I found this note in bios update v A05

"Fixed issue where an external monitor would not display when booting docked with the LCD Lid Closed."

Not exact but i recommend updating the bios to the latest [v A07](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R297113&SystemID=PREC_M4500&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=22213&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=6&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=445817)

Before updating the Bios apply [this urgent patch update](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R271142&SystemID=PREC_M4500&servicetag=&os=W764&osl=en&deviceid=22213&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=1&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=400154) First

Then update your appropriate video driver and video ISV driver [from this page](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&ServiceTag=&SystemID=PREC_M4500&os=W764&osl=en&catid=&impid=)

.

> *Note***
>
> When updating the bios, I always recommend [booting the PC into a clean state](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-7/), then apply the bios update, then revert the settings after the PC reboots.

Comment: Thanks for the advice--I never even thought about updating the BIOS.  But it worked.  At least, on a simple test today.  Thanks for the advice!